# Jira: Flow Item field in Edit Issue>Source Table

Tags: azure, jira, azure-data-factory, jira-rest-api

I am looking for the source table that the column or field "Flow Item" lives in.

I am making use of Jira's official connector for Microsoft Azure to extract Jira data into our Warehouse.

The above is Jira Cloud based solution.

Can anyone please help me identify what the source table name is?

Comment: ` what the source table name is` Not sure what you are referring. The definition of table name or query sql in jira connector ADF document can't give your clues?

Comment: Hi Jay, i am referring to when i use the official Jira connector for Azure i want to know win what table does the column Flow Item live in? Meaning when i pull the Jira data into Azure i want to know what is that table name that has the column inside called Flow item.

Comment: I looked at the documentation from Microsoft but could not find anything.